# How do you change the style of ValidationMessages in Blazor Server Side EditForms?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an `EditForm` as follows:

```
<EditForm class="container-fluid" Context="formContext" Model="@_inputModel" OnValidSubmit="() => OnSubmitInput()">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <!-- other stuff ordered in bootstrap cols and rows --> 
    

    <div class="col-6">
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _inputModel.NumberOfInputChannels"/>
        <label for="stNumberOfChannels" class="form-label">Number of Channels</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stNumberOfChannels" 
            @bind="_inputModel.NumberOfInputChannels">
    </div>

</EditForm>
```

The property of the model corresponding to the form looks like this:

```
[Range(1, 4, ErrorMessage = "Number of Channels must be between 1 and 4!")]
[JsonPropertyName("n-channels")]
public ushort NumberOfInputChannels { get; set; } = 3;
```

My problem is simply, that the message appears too big, thus I want to make it smaller:
[image]

I have already tried to add `class="fs-6"` to the `<ValidationMessage />` tag, but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: The styles for you validation messages are in app.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

1. Modify `validation-message` in your CSS
2. Wrap `ValidationMessage` in a `div` and set whatever CSS you want on the div .

```html
<div class="fs-6">
    <ValidationMessage For="() => myData.Name" />
</div>
```

For reference, the `ValidationMessage` source `BuildRenderTree` looks looks this:

```cs
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var message in CurrentEditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier))
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "validation-message");
            builder.AddMultipleAttributes(2, AdditionalAttributes);
            builder.AddContent(3, message);
            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<ValidationMessage>` has a parameter `AdditionalAttributes` which captures attributes. However it sets the class attribute itself to `validation-message` which can be found in `wwwroot/css`

```
 <ValidationMessage For="() => _inputModel.NumberOfInputChannels"
                    style="font-size: 1rem;"/>
```

`fs-6` is `1rem`

[Source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs,efd85a4768c49606)